# Selecting the smallest number for each ID-group using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, select

I have attribute table with duplicate `"ID"` numbers, i.e. `"1,1,2,2,3,3,....."` and there is a unique number value in another field. I want to select the smallest number for each `"ID"`. How can I perform that?

Below is an image of my Attribute Table

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non program solution is to run table through summary stats tool, case would be page number and stats is minimum of measure. That could create a table of the rows you want to select. In that table add a string field and concatenate the page number and measure to create an "ID" field, do the same with your table above. Then you can use the [relate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/relating-the-attributes-in-one-table-to-another.htm) tools in arcmap to pass a selection. Total time < 3 mins.

Comment: Thanks. it worked smoothly

Comment: Sort and Delete identical might be even faster.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Hornbydd. But if you want to use Python you can use the fact a dictionary can't have multiple keys and sort by value field. Last record in each group/(dictionary key) will be kept.

```py
import arcpy

#Change to match your data
layer = "ak_riks"
group = "LANSNAMN"
value = "Area"

fields = [group, value, "OID@"]

records = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,fields)]
records.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

d = {r[0]:r[2] for r in records}
to_select = d.values()

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=layer, \ 
where_clause="""{0} IN {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=layer, \ 
field=arcpy.Describe(layer).OidFieldName), tuple(to_select)))
```

[image]